# JS I have and array of strings, 'email:password', with these strings, and I need to turn it into an object that separates these values

Tags: javascript

I should have an array of account objects, an account object should be composed by a username and password property e.g:

```
var account = {
     username: 'bla@bla.com',
     password: 'UG384'
};
```

It should be like this, but it is

```
accounts = ['blabla@bla.com:HAS8324', and so forth]
```

Comment: How does  `UG384` convert to `HAS8324`?

Comment: I don't think that was intentional, `bla@blah.com` becomes `blabla@bla.com` as well, I think they are just different random filler text, the author should be a little more consistent though

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `Object.values` return only values of an abject, and *data destruction* to get user and pass and merge them together using *template literal*:

```js
[user, pass] = Object.values(account);
res = `${user}:${pass}`;//"bla@bla.com:UG384"
```

Comment: they need `[ "bla@bla.com:UG384" ]`, not `[ "bla@bla.com", "UG384" ]`

Comment: *"I have an array of strings, 'email:password'. With these strings, and I need to turn it into an object that separates these values*"

Comment: @andymccullough `[ "bla@bla.com:UG384" ]` is their input from the question title

Comment: gotcha, misread it

Comment: @andymccullough the title and the body of the question is very misleading and confusing

Comment: could you please check out the answer? I didn't pay attention at first?